# Dojo/Dijit tabs with images

Tags: dojo

I am creating a dojo tab like so:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
    Item 1
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
        // Load Item Tab
        newItemPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({
                              title:'Item',
                              closable: true,
                              id:'item_tab',
                              href:'/item/1/',
                              }
                      });
        dijit.byId('mainTabs').addChild(newItemPane);
        // Select the Item Tab
        dijit.byId('mainTabs').selectChild("item_tab");
    </script>
</button>
```

Can I dynamically insert an image to the right of the text for `item_tab`?

I've tried:

```
dojo.style('item_tab','background-color','#ff0000');
dojo.style(dijit.byId('item_tab'),'background-color','#ff0000');
```

just to see if I can change the colour to no avail :(

I found something [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/tab-color-control-td160415.html) but I don't quite understand his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to put the icon on the left and you just need to add an iconClass to the content pane.

```
newItemPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({
    title:'Item',
    closable: true,
    id:'item_tab',
    href:'/item/1/',
    iconClass: 'dijitIconUsers'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/L3BBf/

If you need to put it on the right side, you will need to create your own `TabController` and `TabButton`.  (see `dijit/layout/TabController`)

Comment: Yeah. I have custom icons that I want to use

Comment: Custom icons that need to be on the right?  Custom icons on the left would work, just create a css class and use instead of dijitIconUsers.

Comment: Yeah but how do I embed a css class in the title. (or do you mean that `dijitIconUser` refers to a css class and I just create my own css class with `background-image`?)

Comment: Yes, just create your own css class.